# Can you "club together" with something else than money?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

All examples I've seen on the internet refer with this phrase to money. But isn't it possible to club together with, for instance, our group effort/our knowledge and experience/our part of work?

Comment: It sounds like it's splitting the cost between a group of people to receive a benefit for the group as a whole or a third party, as opposed to just splitting the cost of a dinner, e.g. ["going Dutch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_Dutch).

Comment: I think this question could be greatly improved if you include at least a couple of those examples you’ve seen on the internet, along with some links showing where you found them.

Comment: My first thought for "club together" isn't money. I would just use it as an (informal) synonym for "work as a group"

Comment: "Pitch in" is a good alternative that can be used when sharing the effort of something.  It means "join in to help with a task or activity"
e.g.  "The house needs cleaning but if we all pitch-in it'll be done in no time"

Comment: I've only heard this type of phrasing in Indian (subcontinent) English or by those who work with Indian people.  I've come to understand it to mean roughly the same things a 'group'.  Other phrasings include: "let's club it" which tends to shock North Americans who are familiar with this term referring to the violent act.  British or American references are not likely to explain this.

Comment: "Club Together" can also refer to a scenario where a group of people go clubbing together: *There's this really great venue where Skrillex is playing tonight; Let's club together.*

Comment: @JimmyJames The phrase "club together" is common enough in British English and would not be misunderstood as an invitation to jointly beat something with clubs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks.  What about "club it"?

Comment: @JimmyJames That sounds much more likely to end in the death of a baby seal.

Comment: I have encountered requests from Indian business partners to **club together** several orders into one shipment, to save shipping costs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/club-together
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/club-together

**'Club together'** specifically refers to splitting the cost of something between a group of people - it is not used for other divisions of resources or labour.

A term with the broader definition that you are looking for would be **'pool our resources'**, which can be applied to more than just money.

'**[put our heads together](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/put-their-heads-together)**' would be more suited to knowledge or ideas - a group of people might put their heads together to solve a difficult problem, for example.

Comment: I'm not convinced by those definitions. Cambridge doesn't say that the cost has to be financial and Macmillan doesn't even give a definition, just an example circumstance where the phrase could be used. And the OED contradicts; writing an answer now.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34789?redirectedFrom=club+together#eid9192295) (subscription required), **club together** means

> To combine in making up a sum (as the cost or expense of an entertainment, etc.) by a number of individual contributions; to go shares in the cost of anything.
>
> To contribute (as one's share) towards a common stock.

I don't think either of those necessarily requires the cost to be in money. For example, one of the quotations is,

> T. Smollett *Roderick Random* I. xxiii. 212, “This scheme, towards the execution of which my companion clubbed her wardrobe.”

That's not specifically "club together", but I don't see any reason why we couldn't, for example, club together to provide a donation of clothes to charity from our wardrobes.

Indeed, "club" itself has plenty of meanings, such as

> To combine together (or with others) in joint action; to combine as partners or as members of a club.

So, again, it seems reasonable to "club together" in the joint action of using our collective knowledge to solve some problem.